# Is this an autofill bug on Chrome 81?

Tags: google-chrome, auto-form-fill

On my main computer, running Ubuntu 18.04 and Chrome 78, this form works as I would expect - each form can be filled independently.

```css
form {
  border: solid 1px black; 
  padding: 1em; 
  display: inline-block; 
}

form input {
   display: block; 
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label> name<input type = "text" name ="name" />   </label>
  <label> phone<input type = "text" name ="phone" /> </label>
  <label> email<input type = "text" name ="email" /> </label>
  <button type="submit"> submit</button>
</form>

<form>
  <label> name <input type = "text" name ="name"/> </label>
  <label> phone<input type = "text" name ="phone" /> </label>
  <label> email <input type = "text" name ="email"/> </label>
  <button type="submit"> submit</button>
</form>
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/dwjohnston/pen/MZRzKP)

However - on Chrome 81 on a Windows machine - choosing the autofill on the second form will cause the first form to also be filled.

Is this a bug, or correct autofill behaviour?

If so, is there a bug tracker where this is documented?

Comment: You are giving the fields the same `name` in both forms. To distinguish between them, give the fields different names in each form.

Comment: Chrome _"78 and 81"_? Did you perhaps mean "68 and 71"? There is no Chrome 81 yet - the current stable version is 71 and even the canary channel is only 74.

Answer (score 2):

The named fields in an HTML form are stored with their values by the browser
in the
user's profile, so can be reused in other forms via the mechanism of auto-fill.
A field with the same name is then used globally in this website and all other
websites that have fields with the same name.

In the Chromium article of
[Form Autofill](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-autofill)
this can be seen from the structure of the SQLite Database table that stores
these values as pairs, where the table-columns are:
*pair_id, name, value, count*.
It can be seen here that the originating website and the original page URL
do not appear here and have no importance.

You have used standard names for the form fields, which can be found in various
standards: *name, phone, email*. Some browsers even allow one to enter values
for them in the profile definition, which the browser then auto-fills automatically
for all forms using these standard field-names.
The browser stores all field values, not only those that have well-known names.

You have used the same names twice, that the browser will store in your profile, 
to be reused again. When auto-filling, it will use only one of the values you
entered for fields with the same name, based on its internal algorithms,
for example the last-entered or the most-used.
In effect, you have declared that the values in both forms of the fields are
to made identical, which the browser did as requested by auto-filling them with
the same values.

There are other well-known variants of the field-names you used.
For example, besides *name* that you used, there exist
*fname*, *mname* and *lname*, for first, middle and last names.

In HTML5 the
[form standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html)
has been extended, with the addition of the `autocomplete` tag-attribute
that allows to distinguish, for example, between the work and home phone numbers.
For example:

```
<p><label>Customer name: <input name="custname" required autocomplete="shipping name"></label></p>
<p><label>Telephone: <input type=tel name="custtel" autocomplete="shipping tel"></label></p>
<p><label>E-mail address: <input type=email name="custemail" autocomplete="shipping email"></label></p>
```

Useful references:

- [The Chromium Projects - Form Autofill](https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-autofill)
- [How to trigger Autofill in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223168/how-to-trigger-autofill-in-google-chrome)
- [HTML Living Standard - Forms](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html)
  from 24 January 2019

Comment: I feel like this answer doesn't explain the difference in behavior between 79 and 81

Comment: I think that Chrome is moving to better respect the standard, and that this development is motivated by the HTML5 evolution of the handling of form fields. According to what you say, the handling in Chrome 78 was non-standard.